# Taxonomy count per Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, tags, count

Below is the code i use to output the post tag (taxonomy) count/number. I want to be able to split the count based on post type that the taxonomy features in (rather than the total number).

So i have the default "post" Post type, aswell as "blogs", & "pics". I want the taxonomy count to display something like: x posts | x blogs | x Pics

```
            <?php
            $tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "a", 'order' => 'ASC') );
            foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { ?>
                <li>                            
                    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">          
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $tag->name ?></span>
                        <span class="number"><?php echo $tag->count ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to get the number of post per type per term so i created this small function:

```
function get_term_post_count_by_type($term,$taxonomy,$type){
    $args = array( 
        'fields' =>'ids', //we don't really need all post data so just id wil do fine.
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //-1 to get all post
        'post_type' => $type, 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
            )
        )
     );
    $ps = get_posts( $args );
    if (count($ps) > 0){return count($ps);}else{return 0;}
}
```

and once you have this function you can change your code a bit to this:

```
<?php
$ptypes = array('post','blog','pic'); //array with all of your post types
$tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "a", 'order' => 'ASC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { ?>
<li>                            
        <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">          
            <span class="name"><?php echo $tag->name ?></span>
        <span class="number">
            <?php 
                $count = 1;
                foreach($ptypes as $t){
                    echo get_term_post_count_by_type($tag,'post_tag',$t) . " " . $t;
                    if (count($ptypes) != $count){
                        echo " | ";
                        $count = $count + 1;
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </span>
    </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It just outputs "0" for each type (even post which worked before). I assume you put the function into your functions.php file right? Any ideas why this isn't working? Thx

Comment: i changed the lazy coding at the end of the function, try that and make sure the array with the post types has the exact names your post types have.

Comment: Thxs again but still no luck :/. The post types are definitely right as i use them in queries around the site.

Comment: just found the problem, bad copy paste, try the updated function.

Comment: Excellent mate, works gd thx. Minute issue, any way to get rid of the last | separator?

Comment: i added a counter to avoid last separator

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to set `posts_per_page` to `1` so as not to load in all of your posts (but only one), if you have thousands of posts that's not a very eficient way of doing this.

Setting it to `0` won't work, because WP_Query will check `if ( empty( $q['posts_per_page'] ) )`. `0` is `empty()`, so WP_Query won't use it.

`WP_Query` will do a count of the posts that would be found so that can be used instead of selecting all posts then loading them all into memory, making this function more efficient than the accepted one.

```
/**
 * Count number of any given post type in the term
 *
 * @param string $taxonomy
 * @param string $term
 * @param string $postType
 * @return int
 */
function count_posts_in_term($taxonomy, $term, $postType = 'post') {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type' => $postType,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $term,
                'field' => 'slug'
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    return $query->found_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this within a nested loop for each term:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'yourtaxonomynamehere' );
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->count;
    }
}
?>
```