# Why does my custom taxonomy show a total count across all post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-list-table

I have created a custom taxonomy 'season' I have 3 custom post types which I want to use this taxonomy. These are

- Races
- Galleries
- Competitors

Now, when I view the totals within the taxonomy screen  (i.e. the URL in the wp-admin is showing: edit-tags.php?taxonomy=season&post_type=race)

The totals are showing the combined number of posts in this category across all my custom posts, and not just the number of 'race' posts which fall into this category.

Why is this? and how do I get the taxonomy to only show this custom post type?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is currently a [**trac ticket**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14084) on the fact that taxonomy counts are global (include all post types). [Related trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19031).

To fix this you can remove the column and add your own using the `manage_edit-{$taxonomy}_columns` filter:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-season_columns','my_season_columns');
function my_season_columns($columns){
    unset($columns['posts']);
    $columns['cpt_count'] = 'Races';

    return $columns;
}
```

You then tell WordPress what to fill this column with using the `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column` filter. For this you check we are in the 'cpt_count' column and return what ever the count is. You'll need a custom function to do this.

```
add_filter('manage_season_custom_column','my_season_alter_count',10,3);
function my_season_alter_count($value, $column_name, $id ){
    if( 'cpt_count' == $column_name )
        return wpse50755_get_term_post_count_by_type($id,'season','race');

    return $value;
}
```

Lastly, define the custom function `wpse50755_get_term_post_count_by_type`. This was taken [from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/taxonomy-count-per-post-type).

```
function wpse50755_get_term_post_count_by_type($term,$taxonomy,$type){

  $args = array( 
    'fields' =>'ids',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => $type, 
     'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => intval($term)
        )
      )
   );
   $ps = get_posts( $args );

   if (count($ps) > 0){
       return count($ps);
   }else{
       return 0;
   }
 }
```

*This is untested, but conceptually it should work*.

You'll need to do a bit more work to make the column sortable, since you'll need to work out how to tell WordPress to sort the terms in count (post type specific) order.