# Display tags belonging to a specific post type only

Tags: tags, terms

The following code currently indexes all tags for my site (whether attached to a standard post or a custom post) like [this](http://www.furthereast.com/index/)

I want to limit this code to index tags from only a specific custom post (and then taxonomy within that custom post) but I cannot work out what adjustment I need to the initial code (I don't know how to set the $args and I suspect I cannot use `get_terms()` for custom posts).

Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
    $list = '';
$tags = get_terms( 'post_tag' );
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
    }
    if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
            $list .= "\n" . '<div class="index-letter">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</div>';

            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $url = attribute_escape( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) );
                $count = intval( $tag->count );
                $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
                $list .= "\n" . '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a> (' . $count . ')</li>';
                }
            $list .= "\n" . '</li>';
        }
    }
}else $list .= "\n" . '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been successfully using the following code from @StephenHarris from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57449/31545). I have made a small tweak or two to the original code, but the most significant is to name the new `count` object to `count_type` from the original `COUNT*` that was returned by default

Just in short again, the function works exactly like you would normally use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). There is an extra argument however, called `post_type` with will accept an array or string of post type names. When the `post_type` arguments is set, the function uses the `terms_clauses` filter to get the terms by that specific post type only

**NOTE:** One big caution when setting a post type that was not mentioned previously, the function returns two count objects with keys `count` and (now named from `COUNT*`) `count_type`. `count` still retrieves the post count for the specific term **across the board**, not the count for the specific post type. To display the correct count for the post type given, you will have to make use of `count_type` which will display the correct count

As example, here is the returned object when a post type is set

```
object(stdClass)#583 (10) {
  ["term_id"]=>
  string(3) "145"
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "testing"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(7) "testing"
  ["term_group"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  string(3) "145"
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(8) "post_tag"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["count"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["count_type"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

You can see `count` is `4`, this is the total posts from all post types, `count_type` is `2`, this is the amount of posts with the specific tag in the specified post type

Here is the code that goes into your functions.php (*Again, special thanks to @StephenHarris for the original code*)

```
function get_terms_per_post_type( $taxonomies, $args=array() ) {
    //Parse $args in case its a query string.
    $args = wp_parse_args($args);

    if( !empty( $args['post_type'] ) ){

        $args['post_type'] = (array)$args['post_type'];

        add_filter( 'terms_clauses', function ( $pieces, $tax, $args){
            global $wpdb;

            //Don't use db count
            $pieces['fields'] .= ", COUNT(*) AS count_type" ;

            //Join extra tables to restrict by post type.
            $pieces['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
                                 INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id ";

            //Restrict by post type and Group by term_id for COUNTing.
            $post_type = implode( ',', $args['post_type'] );
            $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND p.post_type IN(%s) GROUP BY t.term_id", $post_type );

            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

            return $pieces;

        }, 10, 3 );

    }

    return get_terms($taxonomies, $args);           
}
```

You can use it as follows in your template files

```
$terms = get_terms_per_post_type( 'post_tag', array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "$term->name ( $term->count_type ) </br>";
}
```