# How to get custom post type categories in an array

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to get all categories (custom taxonomy) in array from a specific post type. The taxonomy (category) registered for a specific post type only. And I want to retrieve all categories in an array.
Be like -

```
array(
  'Category Name 1' => 'slug-name-1',
  'Category Name 2' => 'slug-name-2',
  'Category Name 3' => 'slug-name-3',
);
```

It can be get category names by slug or id.

Comment: To build up that array for a given custom taxonomy can be easily achieved, but I find ambiguous what you intend at all. When you say "as list in array from a specific post type" do you mean the custom taxonomy is shared among different post types? And what do you mean with "It can be get category names by slug or id"?

Comment: Use `get_terms` , then loop through the array of term objects and create your array

Comment: @LuisSanz I've updated the question. 
The taxonomy (category) registered for a specific post type only. And I want to retrieve all categories in an array.

Comment: I just wonder if you aren't looking for something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169859/31545)

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at this. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to retrieve the custom taxonomy terms and then build up a custom array to match the structure you want.

Try this:

```
//Get the custom taxonomy terms
$taxonomies = array(
    'name' => 'your_custom_taxonomy' //Edit to match your needs
);

$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomies );

//This array will store the results
$taxonomy_array = array();

//Parse the terms
foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) :

    //Get the taxonomy term name
    $taxonomy_term_name = $taxonomy_term->name;

    //Get the taxonomy term slug
    $taxonomy_term_slug = $taxonomy_term->slug;

    //Push the custom array
    $taxonomy_array[ $taxonomy_term_name ] = $taxonomy_term_slug;

endforeach;
```

The data will be stored in `$taxonomy_array` following the format you provided. You can pass additional arguments to `get_terms()`, such as the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all of the terms that are within all of the registered taxonomies for a specific post type you can use a function like the one below.

```
function termsByTaxonomiesPostType( $postType ) {

    if ( ! post_type_exists( $postType ) ) {
        return [];
    }

    $list       = [];
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $postType );

    if ( empty( $taxonomies ) ) {
        return [];
    }

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms( [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'fields'   => 'all',
        ] );

        // Not an array if you pass 'count' as value for 'fields'.
        if ( ! is_array( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $list[ $taxonomy ] = [];

        // Note: if you want 'id=>slug', 'id=>name', 'names', 'id=>parent', 'ids', 'slugs' only
        // You dont need to perform this.
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $list[ $taxonomy ] = array_merge(
                $list[ $taxonomy ],
                [
                    $term->name => $term->slug,
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    return $list;
}
```

You're list will contain a list of taxonomies and for each taxonomy a list of key => value pairs where the key is the `name` of the term and the value the `slug`.

To note that if you want to retrieve 'id=>slug', 'id=>name', 'names', 'id=>parent', 'ids', 'slugs' only you don't need to perform an additional loop because WordPress will do it for you.

To retrieve one of the associations listed above, just set the string as value for the key `fields`.

Comment: You may also cache the list based on the post type name if you think to use the same function multiple time during the same http request.