# Custom Category widget

Tags: get-posts, categories

I have a custom code in sidebar.php that shows all my categories and number of posts+custom posts. The code is working fine but, since I copied/pasted and modified various other codes from stackexchange forum, I am wondering how efficient the code is.

I don't have any background on php, but at least I can tell the below code is little bit messy. Especially, the code repeats almost same lines three times to show all child categories properly and count normal posts and custom posts separately. The codes shows something like

Grandparent (100+20)

- Parent1 (20+5)

  - Child 1.1 (10+0)
  - Child 1.2 (10+5)
- Parent 2 (80+15)

  - Child 2.1 (40+5)
  - Child 2.2 (40+5)
  - Child 2.3 (0+5)

Is there a way to simplify the code below? and how good/bad is the code in term of speed+efficiency?

```
<aside class="widget widget_categories">
<h3 class="widget-title"><span class="widget-title-tab">Categories</span></h3>  
    <?php $categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ); ?>
    <?php if($categories): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php $cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category=' . $cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
            <?php $cat_probs = get_posts('post_type=probsoln&category=' . $cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
            <?php $count = count($cat_posts); ?>
            <?php $count_prob = count($cat_probs); ?>
            <li class="cat-item" style=""><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($count+$count_prob)"; ?></span>
            <?php $sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ); ?>
            <?php if($sub_categories): ?>
                <ul class="children">
                <?php foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_cat): ?>
                    <?php $sub_cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category=' . $sub_cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
                    <?php $sub_cat_probs = get_posts('post_type=probsoln&category=' . $sub_cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
                    <?php $sub_count = count($sub_cat_posts); ?>
                    <?php $sub_count_prob = count($sub_cat_probs); ?>
                        <li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($sub_cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $sub_cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($sub_count+$sub_count_prob)"; ?></span>
                        <?php $sub_sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ); ?>
                        <?php if($sub_sub_categories): ?>
                            <ul class="children">
                            <?php foreach ($sub_sub_categories as $sub_sub_cat): ?>
                            <?php $sub_sub_cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category=' . $sub_sub_cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
                            <?php $sub_sub_cat_probs = get_posts('post_type=probsoln&category=' . $sub_sub_cat->term_id . '&numberposts=-1'); ?>
                            <?php $sub_sub_count = count($sub_sub_cat_posts); ?>
                            <?php $sub_sub_count_prob = count($sub_sub_cat_probs); ?>   
                                <li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($sub_sub_cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $sub_sub_cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($sub_sub_count+$sub_sub_count_prob)"; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>       
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>       
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>   
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</aside>
```

Comment: There's quite a bit that needs improved, luckily this code is *readable* though.

Can you post the HTML output so any changes can be made sure to match what you have?

Some things you should note, is to not open and close PHP so often. Right inside your <ul> you have 4 PHP statements. You could keep the first `<?php` before $cat_posts and the last `?>` after count( $cat_probs ); and it would be better.

Also, use WP_Query instead of `get_posts`. You can research why, but it's STRONGLY recommended to change. Also I think you could combine most of these category functions into the WP_Query

Comment: I thought I have to put <?php in every line of php code... ;( I am now deleting all redundant codes... Thanks!

Comment: Nope! Take a look at my answer below. All the `<?php` does is that it tells the document that PHP code will follow until the next `?>`.  Also look at this past bin, both of these blocks of code (ripped from yours) are functionally equivalent: https://pastebin.com/Q7wrHrTB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Code Sample Removed, updated based on new answer:

Honestly this doesn't change too much, other than makes it a bit more succinct, and I'll explain the major points of what I've done.

You reuse this code sample a lot:

```
<li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($cat_posts->found_posts+$cat_probs->found_posts)"; ?></span>
```

Inline, this gets relatively hard to read, and if you need to change or add a class to this, it gets a bit more tedious. Since it's repeated three times, you should probably turn it into a function, so at the start I've created a function called `jjycjn_display_link()` that takes the category object, as well as the objects returned by your posts query and probs query, and echo the output automatically, so now all you need to do is use:

```
<?php display_link( $cat, $cat_posts, $cat_probs ); ?>
```

Which is much easier to digest when reading a file like this.

Another thing you can do is assign variables inside an `if` statement. You don't need to assign a variable and then check if it exists, you can do that in one statement. So your

```
$categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
if( $categories ):
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
if( $categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ) ):
```

That will assign `$categories` to the return value of `get_categories()`, and if it returns a [Truthy Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) then it will continue into the statement.

You might even be able to skip assigning the variables like `$cat_posts` and just drop the WP_Query into the `jjycjyn_display_link()` function since you don't use the assigned variable, but I've left it for readability and debugging purposes (easier to debug if you have assigned it to a variable)

Best of luck!

```
<?php
    function jjycjn_display_link( $cat, $posts, $probs ){
        echo '<a href="'. get_category_link($cat->term_id) .'">'. $cat->name .'</a><span class="post_count"> ('. $posts->found_posts + $probs->found_posts .')</span>';
    }
?>
<aside class="widget widget_categories">
<h3 class="widget-title"><span class="widget-title-tab">Categories</span></h3>  
    <?php if( $categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ) ):
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($categories as $cat):
            $cat_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
            $cat_probs = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>
            <li class="cat-item"><?php jjycjn_display_link( $cat, $cat_posts, $cat_probs ); ?>
            <?php if( $sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ) ):
                echo '<ul class="children">';
                foreach($sub_categories as $sub_cat):
                    $sub_cat_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
                    $sub_cat_probs = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>
                    <li class="cat-item"><?php jjycjn_display_link( $sub_cat, $sub_cat_posts, $sub_cat_probs ); ?>
                    <?php if( $sub_sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ) ):
                        echo '<ul class="children">';
                        foreach ($sub_sub_categories as $sub_sub_cat):
                            $sub_sub_cat_posts = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
                            $sub_sub_cat_probs = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>
                            <li class="cat-item"><?php jjycjn_display_link( $sub_sub_cat, $sub_sub_cat_posts, $sub_sub_cat_probs ); ?>
                        <?php endforeach;
                        echo '</ul>';     
                        endif;
                    echo '</li>';     
                endforeach;
                echo '</ul>';   
                endif;
            echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
    endif; ?>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a little bit more? Which part of my code should be replaced by yours?

Comment: Almost all of it. I'll elaborate a bit more with your code wrapping it.

Comment: I've updated the code, you should be able to basically swap it out entirely. It uses far fewer functions calls, a single PHP tag, doesn't rely on expensive `get_post` queries to tally, and should work all the way down to Grand Child categories. I may have a typo or two, but the idea should provide a much easier to maintain and much lighter weight solution than what you have now

Comment: Also, there very well may be a plugin that accomplishes this type of thing already. I don't know for certain, but it may be worth looking at and dissecting how they do it. The above code is basically just a clean-up of the code you provided

Comment: This is working almost as I wanted, but for some reason, it returns 0 for the number of parent and child category (it counts the number of post in grandchild category, though). 
Also, I need to count the numbers of normal posts and a custom posts (having slug probsoln) separately in each category.  Do you have any suggestion to achieve this goal?

Comment: You could probably replace `get_category( $var )` with `get_term_by( 'name', $var )` - replacing the `$var` with the appropriate level's variable.

Unfortunately, using a post type with the same category terms messes up this method I believe, and I'm not entirely certain I can help right now trying to get that to work as well. Your best bet may be to clean up your PHP statements, and replace `get_posts` with `WP_Query` which would be a decent improvement to what you have

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to break terms and taxonomies out by post type natively, according to this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/get-terms-by-custom-post-type. I'd feel bad walking you down a more convoluted solution utilizing the `$wpdb` object, especially if you're just venturing into PHP.

Comment: That's fine as I learned something today, anyway. Thank you so much for your comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Xhynk, I have made a change in my previous messy code. `get_posts` is now changed to `WP_Query` and all unnecessary `<?php` and `?>` pairs are removed. I have no idea if this one is better than the previous one, but it is certainly shorter! There should be a way to call `WP_Query` function only once in each for loop, but I couldn't find a way to do it. I will updated the answer once I get a solution.

```
<aside class="widget widget_categories">
<h3 class="widget-title"><span class="widget-title-tab">Categories</span></h3>  
    <?php $categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
    if($categories):
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $cat):
        $cat_posts = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
        $cat_probs = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>
        <li class="cat-item" style=""><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($cat_posts->found_posts+$cat_probs->found_posts)"; ?></span>
        <?php $sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
            if($sub_categories):
            echo '<ul class="children">';
            foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_cat):
                $sub_cat_posts = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
                $sub_cat_probs = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>
                <li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($sub_cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $sub_cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($sub_cat_posts->found_posts+$sub_cat_probs->found_posts)"; ?></span>
                <?php $sub_sub_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => $sub_cat->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
                    if($sub_sub_categories):
                    echo '<ul class="children">';
                    foreach ($sub_sub_categories as $sub_sub_cat):
                        $sub_sub_cat_posts = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
                        $sub_sub_cat_probs = new WP_Query( array ( 'cat' => $sub_sub_cat->term_id, 'post_type' => 'probsoln' ) ); ?>    
                        <li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($sub_sub_cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $sub_sub_cat->name; ?></a><span class="post_count"><?php echo " ($sub_sub_cat_posts->found_posts+$sub_sub_cat_probs->found_posts)"; ?></span>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach;
                    echo '</ul>';       
                    endif;
                echo '</li>';       
            endforeach;
            echo '</ul>';   
            endif;
        echo '</li>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
    endif; ?>
</aside>
```

Comment: Nicely done! I'm going to edit my answer to reflect a few changes in what you have, but that already looks much better!

Comment: As well, I'm not sure you can call WP_Query once in each loop. You can change `'post_type' => 'probs'` to `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'probs' )` which would work, but then you'd have to loop through that count each post type. It might be better to just stick with the two native queries.

You may also consider installing the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to make sure it's not getting too heavy

Comment: Lastly, once you get a little more adept at PHP, you may want to consider adding a new option that's an associate array of all the posts/probs using [`update_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) function that updates when a post is published or removed so you're running such an expensive query each page load. Until then, consider caching your results using something like WP Super Cache or PHPFastCache to limit queries if they're expensive!