# Get proper tag count for each post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, tags, terms

I am working on a plugin to port over a Druapl 7 installation to WordPress.
I've found some useful tutorials on how to do this for Druapl 6 but Drupal 7 seems to lack any information. Nonetheless, I was able to build the plugin and it works really good.

The issue I am having is getting the correct count (when you view tags from the post type) for terms in each post type. All post types have the same count, not relevant to their post type count.

This **IS NOT** the same as the proposed [duplicate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/taxonomy-count-per-post-type)....

I am using this query:

```
$result = $wpdb->query("
    UPDATE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt
      SET `count` = (
        SELECT COUNT(tr.object_id) FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    )
");
```

This seems to get the correct count but it's wrong (not post type specific, it's all post types). I have tags that are shared across all post types. So when I am in POSTs and I view tags, it shows me all the counts for all post types. The issue is when I click on the number to view the list of posts for the tag, I have none. All post types show the same count. I thought this should count on a per post type basis but it's not.

So my question is, what is my query missing?

I am trying to do this in a single query as there are no fixed post types and looping over every post type is just overkill and unnecessary.

Comment: Nope, not even close... I am asking for the SQL to update the count as this is an import from Drupal. That post is talking about showing the count on a post page, knowing the post-type. I'm not using a built-in function to define every post-type. I am trying to get a single query to do this automatically for all post-types as this is dynamic content and looping over each and every post-type is a little overkill.

Comment: Right, you know I just wanted to help you? SQL query questions are off topic here, [so] is the better place for them, but this concerns the WP database so it's all good I guess.

Comment: Btw. if you'd have looked at the linked questions, than you would've found this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50776/22534), where @StephenHarris says: »There is currently a [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14084) on the fact that taxonomy counts are global (include all post types). [Related trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19031).« Don't know, but just maybe that could concern you, but read up yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I did see a few trac reports but they were last year and stated fixed for some. That talks about categories (I'm dealing with tags) but I think you may be correct on this. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your help. I just needed it to be clear for others that it's not the same. Problem with the Internet, you can't hear my tone ;)

Comment: Sure, no problem and no worries, just clearing things up. Good luck with solving your problem.